# Reindex Pandas DataFrame with sum instead of bfill or ffill

Tags: python, pandas

Say I'm a farmer...and every so often I go out to my fields and pick all the ripe apples, pears and plums.  I keep track of how many of each I pick on each day in a dataframe called `pick_counts`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

pick_counts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, [10,3]),
                  index=pd.date_range('8/16/2004', periods=10, freq='D'), 
                  columns=['apples', 'pears', 'plums'])
```

On my farm, I have a cup that measures rainfall.  And every so often, I check how much rain has fallen **since my last reading**...i.e. each time I check the rainfall in the cup, I dump out the water so it "resets".  I store my rainfall readings in a series called `rainfall`:

```
rainfall = pd.Series(np.random.rand(4), 
                     index=pd.date_range('8/16/2004 12:15PM', 
                                         periods=4, 
                                         freq='80H'))
```

Now as a reasonable farmer, I want to see if the rainfall over a given period has any impact on the number of each fruit that I pick during that period.  So I'd like to make a dataframe which has columns `['apples', 'pears', 'plums', 'rainfall']` and where the rows are the dates from `rainfall`.  In the fruit columns, I would like to see the total number of pieces of that kind of fruit between the time indicated in each row and the the time indicated by the previous row.  I.e. each row would contain data about how much rain fell since the previous row and how much of each kind of fruit was picked since the previous row.

What's the right way to approach this?

I think I want to do something like `reindex` but using a fill method of `sum` (which doesn't exist).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you going to define the rainfall period? Here for example, I have 8-16 as one, 8-17 to 8-19 as the 2nd, and so on.

```
In [38]:

pick_counts['period']=(pick_counts.index.values>=rainfall.index.values[...,np.newaxis]).sum(0)
gbdf=pick_counts.groupby('period').sum()
gbdf.index=rainfall.index
gbdf['rainfall']=rainfall
print gbdf
                     apples  pears  plums  rainfall
2004-08-16 12:15:00      12     15      0  0.799159
2004-08-19 20:15:00      16     28     37  0.461479
2004-08-23 04:15:00      47     47     40  0.780529
2004-08-26 12:15:00       5     33     18  0.118274

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

What the 1st line is doing is to create a column for the periods:

```
In [113]:

print pick_counts
            apples  pears  plums  period
2004-08-16      12     15      0       0
2004-08-17       3      3      7       1
2004-08-18       9     19     18       1
2004-08-19       4      6     12       1
2004-08-20       1      6      7       2
2004-08-21      14     17      5       2
2004-08-22      13      8      9       2
2004-08-23      19     16     19       2
2004-08-24       5     15     15       3
2004-08-25       0     18      3       3

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

And the `rainfall` DF is this:

```
In [114]:

print rainfall
2004-08-16 12:15:00    0.799159
2004-08-19 20:15:00    0.461479
2004-08-23 04:15:00    0.780529
2004-08-26 12:15:00    0.118274
Freq: 80H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I would define the rainfall period to be the time strictly greater than the previous time up until the current time (inclusive).  I.e. the first period is from the beginning of time up to and including the first time given.  The second period if from strictly after the first time up to and including the second time.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing in your `pick_counts['period'] = ...` line?

Comment: I think that is what's equivalent to mine, see edit for what the 1st line gives:

Comment: That's quite helpful.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around the `np.newaxis` command there.

Comment: See the last a few lines of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html, basically what is doing is to generate the empirical cumulative distribution function,